# How to Remove the Last Row in Grid using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have Two buttons in my Wpf UI named as Add,Remove. My requirement is, if i click add button it has to Add new row with two columns. If i click remove button, it has to remove the Last Inserted Row. I am using Grid for this.
I want to remove the Last Row from the Grid. I am able to add rows with 2 columns. I have the code for Remove. But it says some error. I donno how to remove the last inserted row entirely if i click Remove button. I have the following code.

```
public int count = 1;
    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating Rows..
        RowDefinition row0 = new RowDefinition();
        row0.Height = new GridLength(30);
        grid1.RowDefinitions.Add(row0);

        //Creating columns..
        ColumnDefinition col0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        col0.Width = new GridLength(100);
        col1.Width = new GridLength(100);

        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col0);
        grid1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);


        int i = count;
        ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
        cmb.Items.Add("add");
        cmb.Items.Add("remove");

        Grid.SetRow(cmb, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(cmb, 0);

        grid1.Children.Add(cmb);

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        Grid.SetRow(txt, i);
        Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);
        grid1.Children.Add(txt);
        count++;
    }

    private void btn_remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid1.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(count);
        count--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally don't need an additional counter for removing the last row, just use:

```
  grid1.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(grid1.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
```

Comment: Don't forget to also remove the last child/combobox: `grid1.Children.RemoveAt(grid1.Children.Count-1);`